# Enabling Autoplay in Native iOS App

Tags: ios, html, video, uiwebview, autoplay

I'm trying to enable autoplay for video in a native iOS app I'm working on. My company will be developing a full-fledged app this coming year, but I've been tasked with building out a rapid prototype. The point of this prototype is to give us a quick tool for playing with autoplay functionality that will be available through the [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Just to paint a bit more of a picture. Our current website UX is best with autoplay functionality and a lot of our users are asking for this functionality on our mobile version of the site. At the moment we do serve up a slightly different site for mobile, but as you probably know Apple (due to data concerns) has disabled autoplay through JS/HTML5, etc. This is the reason we want to deliver an actual iOS app in the near future.

So I'm brand new to Objective-C and iOS development, but after about a half-day of reading through the Apple developer docs I've managed to get as far as loading our site into a UIWebView. I'm then setting `mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO`. However, I'm not seeing the auto-playback functionality happening in the iOS Simulator.

See more details here:

> mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction A Boolean value that determines
>   whether HTML5 videos can play automatically or require the user to
>   start playing them.
>
> @property(nonatomic) BOOL mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction Discussion
>   The default value on both iPad and iPhone is YES.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 4.0 and later. Declared In UIWebView.h

Here is the contents of my ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>    
@interface myCompanyViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

And here is my ViewController.m:

```
#import "myCompanyViewController.h"

@interface myCompanyViewController ()

@end

@implementation myCompanyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSString *fullURL = @"http://www.mycompany.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_webView loadRequest:requestObj];
    _webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
    _webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

So what am I missing? I appreciate any help and advice you can give.

Comment: Can you share some code on how the autoplay is implemented on the Web side?

Comment: The site is a single-page JS application. We have our own HTML5 player as well as provide several embedded HTML5 players from content partners. So depending on where a video is sourced depends on the player used, but all are HTML5 players with the only differences being skins for the most part. I'm assuming from your question, that we'll need to make sure autoplay attribute is enabled on the player element?  I've read that this attribute is ignored by Apple, but perhaps it isn't once the mediaPlaybackREquiresUserAction is disabled? In a means to respect what is intended by the website?

Comment: You may want to try triggering playback via JavaScript once the page has loaded. I don't think the autoplay attribute works. You'll still need to set `mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction`.

Comment: I'll give that a try. Will let you know how it goes once I've had the chance. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Valjas I know you posted this a couple years ago, but did you discover the method for achieving this and if so, can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Found this of stackoverflow:

"Apple has made the decision to disable the automatic playing of video on iOS devices, through both script and attribute implementations.

In Safari, on iOS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user may be on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, preload and auto-play are disabled. No data is loaded until the user initiates it." - Apple documentation.

Apple's Nanny State!

Comment: I'm aware of that for WebView and websites. It was my understanding that in native apps it could be enabled. Look at the YouTube app for example.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to enable auto play for webview

```
NSString *Str_embbed_video = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                              <html><head>\
                              <style type=\"text/css\">\
                              body {\
                              background-color: black;\
                              color: transparent;\
                              }\
                              </style>\
                              </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
                              <video width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\" controls autoplay=\"true\" poster=\"%@\" webkit-playsinline\> <source src=\"%@\" type=\"video/mp4\" ></video>\
                              </body></html>",webviewFrame.size.width,webviewFrame.size.height,imageurlString,videoUrlString];


[webView loadHTMLString:Str_embbed_video baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];
```